# Same REST endpoint to support Browser and REST clients

Tags: web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, web-applications

Our team is currently looking at developing the interfaces for a new network monitoring system. We are to support access to the system from:

1. a web browser (Javascript/HTML5 based)
2. any REST client (could be a command-line REST shell or some other higher level system, for ex: to do mashups).

We were thinking of providing same REST endpoints at the Server side (Java EE based) to support both types of clients. This is because, we think a browser is also a REST client, in a sense. And because we thought it will avoid any duplication at the server-side. And we are running low on  engineers (which may be a good thing after all!).

We will be doing Asynchronous request/response-handling at the browser using Ajax. And we think any other REST client needs to take care of any asynchrony it wants.

1) Is this how it is usually done these days ?

2) Is this a good approach, regardless of any other consideration?
Or does one need to consider any other aspect, before making this decision ?

3) I think this implies that we are to send all responses as JSON only from the server and do client-side rendering only. Right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoy're right! Here's my opinion:

```
1) Is this how it is usually done these days ?
```

Yes. The most of REST Api were builded on same server side API. This API provide information to the client, whatever is the client side, that must be an browser or command line call.

You can take a look on free [Apigee ebooks](http://apigee.com/about/api-best-practices/all/ebook), especially [this one](http://apigee.com/about/content/web-api-design), to get more information about how to build a powerful Restful api.

```
2) Is this a good approach, regardless of any other consideration? Or does one need to consider any other aspect, before making this decision ?
```

I think is the finest approach, you have one api to manage your services to clients.

```
3) I think this implies that we are to send all responses as JSON only from the server and do client-side rendering only. Right ?
```

Right. Some javascript frameworks, like [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), do all the rendering on browser only with JSON responses from the Rest Client. You can do it with JQuery as well.